# Windows Proxy option not visible under Proxy Menu in Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

While setting up the Charles on a windows machine, under the Proxy menu there should be option to enable Windows Proxy.

Was expecting a Windows Proxy option, something like this:

[image]

But I'm unable to see any option to enable the Windows Proxy on my system:
[image]

Comment: Do you use a company owned PC? If yes may be proxy settings is disabled by admins.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, I'm using company owned PC, but other people are using it.

Comment: You should manually check your Proxy settings in Windows Internet Options if you can enter a proxy there manually. If the fields are grayed-out you know why Charles can not register itself as Windows proxy.

Comment: I can see Automatically Detect settings toggle is On, although Manual Proxy setup is Off. In Fiddler the manual proxy options gets On automatically with all the required fields. However in Charles that is not the case, we have to toggle it On. If you can tell me what we have to enter in those Address and Port fields after switching on Manual Proxy.

Comment: @AyushTrivedi I just upgraded from v4.2.8 to the latest v4.6.5 and also encountered this issue. 'Windows Proxy' *was visible*, now it's not. It's my personal computer, and proxy settings in the control panel *can* be manually configured. Have you resolved this issue?